# How to access NSURLResponse in webViewDidFinishLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I have a `https` request sent to a server, now I want to access the response (`NSURLResponse`) in `webViewDidFinishLoad`. How do I access that?

`didReceiveResponse` is used for handling `https` part, so I can't really use that response there yet.

My current method of didReceiveResponse looks like below

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
   _authenticated = YES;
   [myWebView loadRequest:req];

   [con cancel];

}
```

Comment: A quick skim of google seems to say that there's no direct way, but apparently, the web view caches response -- keyed by the request -- in the NSURLCache sharedURLCache.  e.g. see this probable duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325818/get-uiwebview-response-header

Comment: @danh - it is only applicable for cacheable URLs

Answer (score 0):

I think you could intercept the requests in shouldStartLoadWithRequest https://stackoverflow.com/a/22792754/445887 seems to be a valid answer