# How to get response headers of a request URL from UIWebView Delegates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate, response-headers

I need `response headers` of the `request URL` that I need to recieve and process in `UIWebview Delegate method` webViewDidFinishLoad: ? But I don't understand how to achieve it. Please note that I don't need request headers but response headers.

One idea is to create a `NSUrlConnection` and fire the request again to recieve it in completion block but I don't want to make two calls. There must be some way that it is handled by UIWebView and response headers can be retrieved . I just don't know how to go about it. Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 NSCachedURLResponse *resp = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:webView.request];
```

But this only works for cacheable urls!

Comment: I am not caching the response

Comment: What's about creating a NSUrlConnection and fire the request before UIWebView using?
You can use response such as:
     [webView loadData:responseData MIMEType:[response MIMEType] 
                            textEncodingName:[response textEncodingName] 
                                     baseURL:[response URL]];

Comment: I want to get the response headers for clicks on UIWebview Page. Hence I don't think that is possible in this case.

Comment: Why? You can use shouldStartLoadWithRequest like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22792754/3008827

Comment: great so this way I am making only one request right! Will try it out and ping here. Thanks. But I hoped if there was a way to directly get it in few lines in webview delegate method like what we have for request headers.

Comment: But one doubt.. How shall we handle redirect URLs in this case? Lets say we get a url which is redirecting us to another page. What should be done in that case. Is there a way to detect these like on basis of navigationtype etc?

Comment: I assume that redirects fall under UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther. Call 'return YES;' in this case.
Unfortunately UIWebView does not provide any functionality for getting response headers.

Comment: Ok. I shall do the complete implementation and get back.

Comment: No I ended up using NSURLConnection for the purpose